# How to read (through stream) project icon data?

Tags: c#, manifest, ico

When you click RMB on project, go to properties, you can set icon&manifest for the project.

In the project code I would like to open a stream to read that icon data. How to do this?

*I don't want to adding that icon again manually in resources, besides I have trouble opening stream for it as well ;-).*

Answer (score 0):

```
Icon appIcon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

Comment: Thank you, but as the question states "through stream".